# strategies to implement a ember js popover

Tags: ember.js, popover

I have a popover functionality to be implemented in my project developed using ember js. I have a button, which when clicked should show a popover with a list of action menus.

I tried an example with bootstrap popover, which looks good to our cause, but I am unable to use that as we are not using bootstrap lib and don't want to include it only for this popover feature.

- Is there any inbuilt support from ember js on the popover function yet (we are using ember v0.2.3)? I know it has a [modal implementation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/) but that  will diable all other functions on the page until closed.
- If you are aware of any custom popover impls that can be ported for trial, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Try searching emberobserver.com for addons like http://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-modal-dialog

Comment: shameless plug but if you need a true modal and use foundation 5.5 this addon works great (and it's ember-testing friendly) https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-foundation-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested component would be ideal for this. Rendering into an outlet like the modal examples doesn't make much sense to me.

You will need to handle a click event in your component's .js file.

Use a property on the component like isOpen to keep track of whether the popover should be shown or not.

Use an if isOpen in your component's template to control whether the child component (the popover) gets rendered or not.

**Edit: [Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lafura/2/edit?html,js,output)**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
<script src="//builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.3/ember.debug.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type='text/x-handlebars'
          data-template-name='application'>
     <p>The element below is a component.<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
     {{popover-item text='click or hover for popover' class='popover-wrapper'}}
  </script>


  <script type='text/x-handlebars'
          data-template-name='components/popover-item'>  
      <a href='#' class='popover-link'>{{text}}</a>
      {{#if isOpen}}
        {{popover-menu isOpen=isOpen}}
      {{/if}}
  </script>


  <script type='text/x-handlebars'
          data-template-name='components/popover-menu'>
    {{#if isOpen}}
      <div class='popover'>
        <ul>        
          <li><a href='#'>popover item one</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>popover item two</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>popover item three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    {{/if}}
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
  return [];
});

App.PopoverItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  isOpen: false,

  click: function() {
    this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
  },

  openPopover: function() {
    this.set('isOpen', true);
  }.on('mouseEnter'),

  closePopover:function() {
    this.set('isOpen', false);
  }.on('mouseLeave')
});
```

CSS (very very rough)

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.popover-link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #6FAEEC;
}
.popover-link:hover {
  background: #70B5F9;
}
.popover-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.popover-link {}
.popover {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
  .popover ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .popover a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px  10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef; #efefef;
  }
  .popover a:hover {
    background: #efefef;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have a similar opinion on how the popovers should differ from modal. I am not able to access the JSbin URL posted in your reply, can you please check that?

Comment: Maybe the JSBin service was down or something. Works for me now. Here is the full link. I will edit the post with the code for the solution.

Comment: @An1711 I've updated my answer with the code from the demo. thx.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to get to the demo, can you please let me know where can I find the helpers for {{popover-item}} and menus? Is there any addon that you've used?

Comment: i'm just using vanilla Ember Components. No Addons at all. This is all built-in Ember functionality.

Comment: If this answers your question, would you mind clicking 'Accepted'? I'm just trying to get over 50 rep so I can unlock the ability to comment on other people's answers

Comment: fiddle is not wokring

Comment: @ThilinaDinithFonseka it worked for me just now in firefox. What isn't working for you?

Comment: @ChristopherMilne hi now it is working. i was trying with chrome and it didnt render anything in output tab.